# Sorting table after filtering d3

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

So I have a table that filters on keydown in some input. I'm then trying to sort the remaining rows. I've tried a number of things, the attempt below works on the idea that I create the table with the stuff on @rows, and then seek to sort using another selection over the same elements that has backbone models attached to it(I need there to be backbone models for other reasons).

```
    renderTable:()=>
    @table =    d3.select("#search-results-area").append("table").attr("id",@tableId).attr("class","visualization-panel")
    @thead = @table.append("thead")
    @tbody = @table.append("tbody")
    @input = @table.append("input").attr("id",@inputId).on("keydown",(d)=>
        toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
        window.setTimeout((()=> 
            toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 



            @rows.filter((d)=>
                        return d 
                ).remove()
            @rows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(@collection.models).enter().append("tr")
            @rows.filter((d)=>
                if @filterFunc(toFilter,d)
                    return d
                ).selectAll("td").data((model)=>
                    return @columns.map((column)=>
                        return {column : column, val : model.get(column)}
                        )
                    ).enter().append("td").text((d)=>
                        for column in @columns
                            if d.column == column
                                return d.val


                        )


            # @currentlyDisplayedRows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(@collection.models.filter((d)=>
            #       console.log "TO FILTER"
            #       console.log toFilter
            #       if @filterFunc(toFilter,d)
            #           console.log d
            #           return d
            #   )).exit().remove()
            @currentlyDisplayedRows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(@collection.models).filter((d)=>
                if @filterFunc(toFilter,d)
                    return d

            ).remove()


            ),1000)

        )

    @columns = @json["Columns"]
    @initializeSortingFunctionManager(@columns)
    @thead.append("tr").selectAll("th").data(@columns).enter().append("th").text((col)-> return col).on("click",(d)=> 

        @currentlyDisplayedRows.sort((x,y)=>
            xVal = x.get(d)
            yVal = y.get(d)
            func = @sortingFunctionManager[d](xVal,yVal)
            return func
        )
    )
    @tbody.selectAll("tr").attr("class","spacing center-text")
    @renderTableBody()
```

Also, with the above method, I get a d3 error - Cannot call insertBefore of null.

What's wrong with this code/how do I achieve sorting of filtered data?

UPDATE-

ok I stepped through using the debugger, as I stepped through I noticed that the sorting was working, however, once we got to the point of execution at the end of the click function, the entire table was re-rendered in its original form.

Comment: er, apparently not? My html looks fine when I append stuff. This seems to be more a problem of my understanding of how my data is being bound.

Comment: Have you considered using the [sort function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-sort)?

Comment: that's what I'm doing - @currentlyDisplayedRows.sort(...
Weird stuff is appearing after the final return of the callback

Comment: But you're only doing that on click and not when filtering if I see it correctly?

Comment: well I'm doing it when the headings of the table are clicked, so there's a sort when a column header is clicked, it should sort the currently displayed rows (the ones that exist after filter)

Comment: So it works before but not after filtering? Did you verify that `@currentlyDisplayedRows` is updated correctly?

Comment: yeah - it's exactly the rows that I want. The UPDATE also shows that - the sorting is working, but then something wonky happens after the callback to the click

Comment: Sounds like we would need a complete example to debug this :)

Comment: er, what would entail that?

Comment: I don't mind providing one, the above code basically renders all the stuff that I think is relevant

Comment: The point would be to have it in a form where I can actually try things (i.e. code and data). At the moment, I can only guess -- I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: oh, so you want me to dummy models and collections?

Comment: As I've said, something that I can play around with and that exhibits the same behaviour, preferably on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar.